# Using SQL how do I get back only the entries with the same string length from two different columns?

Tags: sql

I have a name(the country) and a capital column inside my world table. I want to show only the name and capital that have the same number of characters. Like Greece and Athens that both equal 6 characters. I'm trying to use the LENGTH function, but unsure of what I'm doing wrong.

SELECT name, capital FROM world
WHERE LEN(name) = LEN(capital);

Comment: What is the error? In addition, note that there is a redundant comma (,) after `capital`.

Comment: I'm actually not getting an error. I'm doing SQL practice problems from a website called SQLZOO.com and it doesn't give me error messages.      https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_from_WORLD_Tutorial  it's problem 11 on the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is a redundant `,` between `capital` and `FROM`.
2. In SQL you use `=` to compare, and not `==`.
3. Looks like the site that you provided supports `LEN` function in order to get the length of a string.

`SELECT name, capital FROM world WHERE LEN(name) = LEN(capital);`

Answer (score 0):

You should not put comma(,) in front of "FROM" clause and you should use one equal to "=".

This should works -

```
SELECT name, capital FROM world WHERE LENGTH(name) = LENGTH(capital);
```